# Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode in cypress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cypress, octal, web-api-testing

I wrote a test case using cypress for a POST method and I've a datetime variable and if I pass like datetime and as it starts with 0 it is giving me Legacy octal literals are not allowed compiling error.

Here is the test script

```
describe('Create New Patient', function(){
    it('Creates new patient', function(){
        cy
        .request('POST', 'http://localhost:5002/api/v1/patients', { first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Dane', date_of_birth: 03041990 })
    .then((response) => {
        expect(response.body).to.have.property('first_name', 'Jane') // true
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked using **parseInt**

```
  body: { first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Dane', date_of_birth: parseInt('19920704')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use moment() and add the variable to the request? Something like this:

```
date = moment('1990-04-02', 'DDMMYYYY')
describe('Create New Patient', function(){
    it('Creates new patient', function(){
        cy
        .request('POST', 'http://localhost:5002/api/v1/patients', { first_name: 'Jane', last_name: 'Dane', date_of_birth: date })
    .then((response) => {
        expect(response.body).to.have.property('first_name', 'Jane') // true
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work.

This is the response

Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

This error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

Check your console for the stack trace or click this message to see where it originated from.

Comment: @Ruby4Rails You should install moment and try that again.